# Format usb and confirm all zeros

Tags: command-line, usb, format, dd

I want to format my usb drive and confirm that it has been filled with all zeros.
For formatting this is the command I am using:
`sudo mkfs.vfat -I /dev/sdb`

How do I confirm the device is filled with all zeros through the command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apply `dd`, and `tr` for virtual inspection:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb | tr '\0' 0
```

Apply `dd` and `grep` for automatic checking:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb | grep -zq . && echo non zero
```

*The above is significantly slower than the optimized command below:*

```
grep -zq . /dev/sdb && echo non zero
```

`grep -z` reads in null-delimited lines. If all bytes are null, then each line is empty, so `.` should never match.

Of course, this won't be true for a formatted partition - the format system will be using some bytes and they will be non-null.

Comment: Is that slower or faster than `hexdump`? It will print the first line of 16 bytes out as hexadecimal figures and then print [...] and skip out every subsequent line that equals to the previous one.

Comment: @ByteCommander no idea. `hexdump` might be faster.

Comment: Oh right I thought a format would write all zeros to the device. My understanding is incorrect so?

Comment: @homeGrown it will write zeros, and then create the entries that the filesystem requires.

Comment: @muru so the command I would need then to write all zeros would just be dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb?

Comment: @homeGrown yes. Use an appropriate value of `bs`, so that it doesn't do byte-by-byte.

Comment: @muru I edited your answer to reflect the optimized solution without `dd`.

Comment: @muru Sorry I know probably not right place for this question but the grep -z wont work on mac. I need script to run on linux and mac.  Any idea why not or how to make it work

Comment: @homeGrown Use homebrew to install GNU grep. And next time, ask cross-platform questions on [unix.se].

Answer (score 11):

I'll throw my hat into the ring here as well.  One alternative that I love to use is `scrub`.  It is in the repositories, so to install it from a terminal window type in:

```
sudo apt-get install scrub
```

`scrub` supports many different types of scrubbing patterns

```
Available patterns are:
  nnsa          3-pass   NNSA NAP-14.1-C
  dod           3-pass   DoD 5220.22-M
  bsi           9-pass   BSI
  usarmy        3-pass   US Army AR380-19
  random        1-pass   One Random Pass
  random2       2-pass   Two Random Passes
  schneier      7-pass   Bruce Schneier Algorithm
  pfitzner7     7-pass   Roy Pfitzner 7-random-pass method
  pfitzner33   33-pass   Roy Pfitzner 33-random-pass method
  gutmann      35-pass   Gutmann
  fastold       4-pass   pre v1.7 scrub (skip random)
  old           5-pass   pre v1.7 scrub
  dirent        6-pass   dirent
  fillzero      1-pass   Quick Fill with 0x00
  fillff        1-pass   Quick Fill with 0xff
  custom        1-pass   custom="string" 16b max, use escapes \xnn, \nnn, \\
```

To use `scrub` to fill the drive with all `zeros` first make sure the drive is not mounted.  Then run the following line (`-p` means pattern to use):

```
sudo scrub -p fillzero /dev/sdX
```

then you should see something like this:

```
scrub: using Quick Fill with 0x00 patterns
scrub: please verify that device size below is correct!
scrub: scrubbing /dev/sdh 31260704768 bytes (~29GB)
scrub: 0x00    |.....                                           |
```

Some of the patterns used for scrubbing should have a `verify` pass to make sure the scrubbing passed.

If you would like, you can add the `hexdump` (as in Byte Commander's answer) or any of the other answers to the end for verification.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

My suggest would be `hexdump`. It displays the content of any file or device in hexadecimal format as rows of 16 byte, but if two subsequential lines are equal, it omits them.

Here's an example output of the 512 MB file `virtualdevice` which is filled with zeroes only on the current directory of my HDD. The leftmost column is the offset of the line in hexadecimal notation, the 8 following columns are the actual data, grouped in two bytes (4 hexadecimal characters):

```
$ hexdump ./virtualdevice 
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
20000000
```

---

### Performance:

I made the effort and compared my solution to the others by real run time and CPU time for the described example file (512 MB, containing only binary zeroes, located on HDD).

I measured every solution with the `time` command two times with freshly cleared disk cache and two times with the file already being cached. The time names equal those of the `time` command, and the additional row `CPU` is just the sum of the `USER`+`SYS` times. It can exceed the `REAL` time because I'm running a dual-core machine.

For most people, the interesting figures are `REAL` (time from begin to end, as if measured with a stopwatch. This also contains IO wait and CPU time of other processes) and `CPU` (CPU time which is actually occupied by the command).

**Summary:**

The best performance has **muru**'s optimized second version (`grep -zq . DEVICE`) which uses incredibly few CPU processing time.
Rank 2 share `cmp /dev/zero DEVICE` (**kos**' optimized solution) and my own solution `hexdump DEVICE`. There's nearly no difference between them.
To pipe the data from `dd` to `cmp` (`dd if=/dev/zero | cmp - DEVICE` - **kos**' unoptimized solution) is very inefficient, the piping seems to consume much processing time.
Using `dd` and `grep` shows the by far worst performance of the tested commands.

**Conclusion:**

Although the most critical part of operations like these is the IO access time, there are significant differences in the processing speed and efficiency of the tested approaches.

If you are very impatient, use the second version of **muru**'s answer (`grep -zq . DEVICE`)!
But you can as well use either the second version of **kos**' answer (`cmp /dev/zero DEVICE`) or my own (`hexdump device`), as they have almost as good performance.
However, my approach has the advantage that you immediately see the file contents and can approximate how many bytes differ from zero and where they are located. If you have much alternating data though, the output will grow large and it will probably slow down.

What you should avoid in any case is to use `dd` and pipes. The performance of `dd` could probably be improved by setting a suitable buffer size, but why doing it the complicated way?

Please also note again that the test was done on a file on my disk instead of an actual device. Also the file contained only zeroes. Both affects the performances.

**Here are the detailed results:**

- `hexdump ./virtualdevice` (my own solution):

  ```
          |    Uncached:      |    Cached:
   Time:  |  Run 1:   Run 2:  |  Run 1:   Run 2:
  --------+-------------------+------------------
     REAL |  7.689s   8.668s  |  1.868s   1.930s
     USER |  1.816s   1.720s  |  1.572s   1.696s
      SYS |  0.408s   0.504s  |  0.276s   0.220s
      CPU |  2.224s   2.224s  |  1.848s   1.916s
  ```
- `dd if=./virtualdevice | grep -zq . && echo non zero` (**muru**'s unoptimized solution):

  ```
          |    Uncached:      |    Cached:
   Time:  |  Run 1:   Run 2:  |  Run 1:   Run 2:
  --------+-------------------+------------------
     REAL |  9.434s  11.004s  |  8.802s   9.266s
     USER |  2.264s   2.364s  |  2.480s   2.528s
      SYS | 12.876s  12.972s  | 12.676s  13.300s
      CPU | 15.140s  15.336s  | 15.156s  15.828s
  ```
- `grep -zq . ./virtualdevice && echo non zero` (**muru**'s optimized solution):

  ```
          |    Uncached:      |    Cached:
   Time:  |  Run 1:   Run 2:  |  Run 1:   Run 2:
  --------+-------------------+------------------
     REAL |  8.763s   6.485s  |  0.770s   0.833s
     USER |  0.644s   0.612s  |  0.528s   0.544s
      SYS |  0.440s   0.476s  |  0.236s   0.264s
      CPU |  1.084s   1.088s  |  0.764s   0.808s
  ```
- `dd if=/dev/zero | cmp - ./virtualdevice` (**kos**' solution unoptimized):

  ```
          |    Uncached:      |    Cached:
   Time:  |  Run 1:   Run 2:  |  Run 1:   Run 2:
  --------+-------------------+------------------
     REAL |  7.678s   6.539s  |  3.151s   3.147s
     USER |  2.348s   2.228s  |  2.164s   2.324s
      SYS |  3.672s   3.852s  |  3.792s   3.516s
      CPU |  6.020s   6.080s  |  5.956s   5.840s
  ```
- `cmp /dev/zero ./virtualdevice` (**kos**' solution optimized):

  ```
          |    Uncached:      |    Cached:
   Time:  |  Run 1:   Run 2:  |  Run 1:   Run 2:
  --------+-------------------+------------------
     REAL |  6.340s   9.183s  |  1.660s   1.660s
     USER |  1.356s   1.384s  |  1.216s   1.288s
      SYS |  0.640s   0.596s  |  0.428s   0.360s
      CPU |  1.996s   1.980s  |  1.644s   1.648s
  ```

**Commands used:**

For all four tests I ran the following procedure *twice* to reduce inaccuracies, replacing `<COMMAND>` with the exact command from the headline of each table.

- Let the kernel drop all disk caches:

  ```
  sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
  ```
- First timed run (uncached), file gets loaded into the cache during this:

  ```
  time <COMMAND>
  ```
- Second timed run (cached). This time most of the data is taken from the disk cache in RAM, therefore it's much faster than when accessing the disk directly:

  ```
  time <COMMAND>
  ```

Comment: You have piqued my interest here.  :)

Comment: The `dd` vs without `dd` probably should be done for `grep` as well. Also, do post the code you used to test this.

Comment: I demend a new test! My test shows different things! http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25479599#25479599. I'll post some graphs!

Comment: @kos Test, post and edit whatever you want, my fingers start to hurt from typing! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Using `cmp` (thanks to muru for having pointed out the silliness of using a pipe):

```
sudo cmp /dev/zero /dev/sdX
```

If you get an output such as this one:

```
cmp: EOF on /dev/sdX
```

The drive is zero-filled.

```
% dd if=/dev/zero of=foo iflag=fullblock bs=1M count=1 && sync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1,0 MB) copied, 0,00226603 s, 463 MB/s
% cmp /dev/zero foo
cmp: EOF on foo
```

Comment: You can just use `/dev/zero` directly for `cmp`, I think.

Comment: Indeed. It's much faster directly without `dd`!

Comment: @muru Indeed, pure silliness.